# How do I link to LibZip?

Tags: ubuntu, homebrew, libzip

I installed libzip on ubuntu using brew: `brew install libzip`. That seemed to have worked and I can see it in the Cellar. Running `brew link libzip` reports that it's already linked.

However, when trying to install a package that requires it (https://github.com/yjxiong/dense_flow), I am getting the following error suggesting that it can't find libzip. Any idea why or what else I should set?

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X - Success
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "3.2.0") 
-- Found PkgConfig: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Could NOT find LIBZIP (missing: LIBZIP_LIBRARY) 
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found version "3.6.7") 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBZIP_LIBRARY
    linked by target "extract_gpu" in directory /.../dense_flow
    linked by target "extract_cpu" in directory /.../dense_flow
    linked by target "extract_warp_gpu" in directory /.../dense_flow
    linked by target "denseflow" in directory /.../dense_flow
```